# Sybase JDBC get generated keys

Tags: insert, sqlanywhere, identity-column, lastinsertid

In Postgres, I can write

```sql
INSERT .. RETURNING *
```

To retrieve all values that had been generated during the insert. In Oracle, HSQLDB, I can use

```java
String[] columnNames = ...
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql, columnNames);
// ...
stmt.execute();
stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
```

To retrieve all values that had been generated. MySQL is a bit limited and only returns columns that are set to `AUTO_INCREMENT`. But how can this be done with Sybase SQL Anywhere? The JDBC driver does not implement these methods, and there is no `INSERT .. RETURNING` clause, as in Postgres. Is there way to do it, other than maybe running

```sql
SELECT @@identity
```

immediately after the insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My current implementation executes three consecutive SQL statements:

```sql
-- insert the data first
INSERT INTO .. VALUES (..)

-- get the generated identity value immediately afterwards
SELECT @@identity

-- get the remaining values from the record (possibly generated by a trigger)
SELECT * FROM .. WHERE ID = :previous_identity
```

The third statement can be omitted, if only the `ID` column is requested